# Opening new appt in public calendar on MS Outlook

Tags: autohotkey, outlook-2007

I need to automatically pull up a new appointment in Microsoft Outlook (I'm making a script so automate some things).

I use this:

```
Run, "%programfiles%\Microsoft Office\Office12\Outlook.exe" /c ipm.appointment
```

which brings up my personal outlook calendar.  I need it to open up a new appointment for my public (corporate environment) outlook calendar.  I can not for the life of me figure this out.  If anyone can offer any advice it would be appreciated.

I am coding this in AutoHotKey so if there is a better way to do this than using the Run command I'm all ears.

I appreciate any advice you can give.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the profile command line switch;

```
/profile profilename
```

so you should use

```
Run, "%programfiles%\Microsoft Office\Office12\Outlook.exe" /c ipm.appointment /profile profilename
```

See http://www.outlook-tips.net/howto/commandlines.htm